# Why we always need a Update immediate next to AddNew in ADO vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, ado

I am Looking for a more deeper concept about `rs.AddNew,rs.Update`. Why we always need a `Update` immediate next to `AddNew` in ADO vbscript?

```
Dim cn As New adodb.Connection
Dim rs As New adodb.Recordset
Dim cmd As New adodb.Command

cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=alexverb2;uid=sa;pwd=foo$bar00;"

cn.Open
rs.Open "select * from xxx..aa1", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

Dim fieldsArray(1) As Variant
fieldsArray(0) = "intf"
fieldsArray(1) = "charf"
Dim values(1) As Variant
values(0) = 4
values(1) = "as"
rs.AddNew fieldsArray, values
rs.Update
```

How `ADO GetString()` method speed up the process, what the concept we deals with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to update/commit changes immediately after modifying data. It's an important feature of database management systems to initialize a coherent set of changes and postpone the 'real writing' until the system has made sure all the modifications can be done successfully. See [UpdateBatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee266587%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) for a bit of background and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6576078/603855) for code and discussion.

**ADDED:**

While I don't want to encourage multiple question: `GetString()` (and `GetRows()`) are two methods that make the **retrival** of information easier by doing the loops 'under the hood'. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: But every document is telling that `update needed after Addnew` which makes me confused. Can you use my example and define these two methods what would happened if we don't use `update` and If we use?

Comment: You are really my `carrier driver in the world of Programming`. Thanks Sir to have my words importance in you. :)

Comment: From your referred post[Bulk insert records into Access using Vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574462/bulk-insert-records-into-access-using-vbscript/6576078#6576078) I have some questions(You can take my questions as my learning's) - (a) What the Purpose such `Case- Bob` to put there? what was your thought. (b) what the purpose was to set these sentences in your code - `WScript.Echo "oRs.CursorLocation: ", oRs.CursorLocation`,`WScript.Echo "oRs.CursorType: ", oRs.CursorType` and `WScript.Echo "oRs.LockType: ", oRs.LockType`

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU -I used one script to compare/contrast three approaches to solve one problem, the names (bob, trout, eh) in the Selects set specific attributes and code sequences, some of them are displayed via WScript.Echo.

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU - no, as I said: the Selects are the way to have just one script for the three approaches (using a debugger to step thru the code may be of help).

Comment: What the purpose (means what you tried to show) of these statements `oRs.CursorLocation`,`oRs.CursorType:` and `oRs.LockType`?

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU - use the ADO docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx to learn about ADO. If you need further help, post focused question.

Comment: Okay! Ekkehard as you wish,but my second question in the description you might overlooked. Is it so? :)